# Dagger 2 error: dependency “cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor”

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm trying to use Dagger 2 in my Android project. For starters, I want to make use of two components responsible for injecting application-wide and activity-wide dependencies respectively. As a basic reference, among other things I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32227842/1815052).

So there are two different ways of setting relationship between components: with the `@Subcomponent` annotation and with the `dependencies` parameter.

1. If I go with the first one, my `AppContextComponent` works fine. But as soon as I try to inject dependency from the `ActivityContextComponent`, I get this build-time error:

> Error:com.example.ui.activity.MainActivity cannot be provided without
>   an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated
>   method.

2. With the second approach, I get this error for all dependencies.

Knowing that I **do** have provision methods, this error message is frankly of no use. Here is a couple of other possible sources of this error I've managed to google out but they don't seem to be the case:

1. [Scoping problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30396152/1815052).
2. [Ambuiguity due to the same return type from different provision methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30552775/1815052) (the problem persists even if I remove methods providing `Context`).

The following code is in Kotlin but I reckon it should be pretty straightforward.

**Application component**

```
object AppContext {
    // a singleton used in place of a Java static field
    @JvmStatic lateinit var graph: AppContextComponent
}

@ApplicationScope @Component(modules = arrayOf(AppContextModule::class))
interface AppContextComponent {
    fun inject(fragment: BaseFragment)

    fun newActivityContextComponent(module: ActivityContextModule): ActivityContextComponent
}

@Module
class AppContextModule(val app: MyApplication) {
    @Provides @ApplicationScope @ForApplication
    fun provideContext(): Context {
        return app;
    }

    @Provides @ApplicationScope
    fun provideMyApplicationContext(): MyApplication {
        return app;
    }
}
```

**Activity component**

```
object ActivityContext {
    @JvmStatic lateinit var graph: ActivityContextComponent
}

@ActivityScope @Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(ActivityContextModule::class))
interface ActivityContextComponent {
    fun inject(fragment: BaseFragment)
}

@Module
class ActivityContextModule(val activity: MainActivity) {

    // Worth pointing out is that the provision methods are not used. 
    // That is, no code is being generated for them.

    @Provides @ActivityScope @ForActivity
    fun provideContext(): Context {
        return activity;
    }

    @Provides @ActivityScope
    fun provideMainActivityContext(): MainActivity {
        return activity;
    }
}
```

And below is how these components are used.

**Application**

```
class MyApplication : SugarApp() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AppContext.graph =
            DaggerAppContextComponent
                    .builder()
                    .appContextModule(AppContextModule(this))
                    .build()
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ActivityContext.graph = 
            AppContext.graph
                 .newActivityContextComponent(ActivityContextModule(this))
    }
}
```

**BaseFragment** (where the actual injection happens)

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {
    // works fine
    @Inject @ForApplication lateinit var myApplication: MyApplication

    // fails with "cannot be provided" error
    @Inject @ForActivity lateinit var myActivity: MainActivity

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ActivityContext.graph.inject(this)
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT**

The gist is:

If you use dagger's `@Subcomponent`s, make sure you don't have a method in the parent `@Component` that injects into the same target class as your subcomponent does.

Dagger will get confused and will try to generate code to inject into the target directly from the parent component, while it doesn't have the needed module(s) to satisfy the injected dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I even tried removing qualifiers together with the clashing provision methods.

Comment: @SqueezyMo after you removed all clashing methods, did you, by any chance, still have two `@Provides` methods with the same *name*?

Comment: No, I only have two methods left: `provideMainActivityContext()` in `ActivityContextModule` and `provideMyApplicationContext()` in `AppContextModule`.

Comment: @SqueezyMo I assume your `build.gradle` is also in order, with kapt stuff like `generateStubs`? Is this project something you can share somewhere?

Comment: Sure. It's a pet [project](https://github.com/squeezymo/GPSAlarm) where I just want to play around with some libs.

Comment: @SqueezyMo took me a while to figure out, please confirm on your machine: I removed this line `fun inject(fragment: BaseFragment)` from `AppContextComponent`, leaving it only in `ActivityContextComponent`. I think dagger was confused by this.

Comment: It finally works! And it makes perfect sense now. The funny thing is, I tried this at one point but another way around. It was my major misunderstanding of how subcomponents work: I thought a component was exposing its subcomponents' dependencies, rather than a subcomponent sharing its parent component's graph. Thank you for a solution and your time, greatly appreciated!

Comment: guys can you share some tutorials for understanding subcomponents.. I'm facing same issue. but removing inject removes error but makes app crash